# How to prevent common ground circuits messing with each other

Tags: ground, grounding, basic, component-selection, interference

I made an Arduino based 18650 battery tester that has 4 identical circuits that charge and drain.

Testing one battery at a time gives one set of results which I deem to be correct but testing more than one can give skewed result sets all around.

I assumed this was because each battery can be on different charge/drain cycles at any given time and is interfering.

I rewired all the common grounds to one exact point on the Arduino and used the exact same length cables. This helped a little bit but there is still a difference.

How would you go about resolving this in a way simple folk like me can understand?
Like a basic component I could put in between the negative of each battery to isolate them?

[image: diagram]

**Edit:** 
Added diagram (there are 4 identical circuits all connected to the same GND). I failed to mention that the batteries are not powering anything. The 5v 4A PSU powers the arduino & four chargers. The charger boards should be fully powered off while draining & vice versa

Comment: No circuit usually means no help.

Comment: The problem probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Always use a BMS or battery balancer for extended to rated life, otherwise weakest cell degrades the fastest.

Comment: Updated with diagram